# Como fazer um "Trigger Genérico" no SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Olá eu tenho no meu banco de dados em todas as tabelas os seguintes campos

**DateTime CriadoEm | DateTime ModificadoEm**

Queria saber se tem um maneira de fazer um trigger genérico para controlar esses campos, pois 
quando inserir, o `CriadoEm` e `ModificadoEm` receberão o msm valor NOW()...

E na hora do update nas tabelas, apenas o `ModificadoEm` receberá NOW()...

Seria uma trigger genérica para as tabelas after inser e after update

É possível?

Comment: Você quer um trigger só para todas as tabelas? Isso não é possível, mas você pode gerar os triggers para cada tabela automaticamente.

Comment: Vlw @NullUserException

Comment: Nâo conheço muito de SQL Server, não sei nem se isso é suportado, mas no Oracle e no Postgre o que eu costumava fazer era criar um stored procedure com o código e criava os triggers para cada tabela chamando esse procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é uma solução para o trigger do update, mas talvez bom para o CriadoEm:

(pode variar um pouco de dialeto SQL para outro, mas quase todos permitem coisa do tipo)

Ao criar a tabela use:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   ..definicao dos campos..
   CriadoEm datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   ModificadoEm datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Assim, para todo registro novo, o campo CriadoEm e ModificadoEm vai obter a data da criação do registro, se você não informar nenhum valor.

Quanto a futuros updates, aí ainda ficam duas possibilidades:

- Usar trigger mesmo
- Ou, se o seu DB permitir, inserir null no campo modificadoEm, (e definir o mesmo como NOT NULL) para que ele pegue o valor default (só testando no seu DB em específico, pra ver se funciona). No MySQL, por exemplo, você deve usar o tipo `TIMESTAMP` para que isto ocorra.

### Solução **específica do MySQL** para manter o ModificadoEm atualizado sem trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
   ..definição dos outros campos..
   ModificadoEm TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Resta ver se o SQL que você está usando tem coisa do tipo.

Answer (score 3):

O script a seguir cria *triggers* para todas as tabelas de um database:

```
exec sp_MSForEachTable 'CREATE TRIGGER [?_Update] ON ? FOR UPDATE AS 
BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON update ? set ModificadoEm = GETDATE() 
from ? updatedTable inner join inserted i 
on i.$identity = updatedTable.$identity
END'
```

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente não dá para criar um *trigger* genérico para múltiplas tabelas.

Contudo, como os *triggers* possuirão a mesma finalidade em todas elas, você pode gerá-los automaticamente, conforme apontado pelo NullUserException.

Para facilitar seu trabalho de criar um *trigger* de cada vez seria interessante, por exemplo, gerá-los através de um laço que percorresse todas as tabelas de seu banco:

```
declare @TABLE_NAME sysname

select @TABLE_NAME = min(TABLE_NAME) from seuBanco.information_schema.tables

while (@TABLE_NAME is not null)
    begin
        /*Criar trigger after insert*/

        /*Criar trigger after update*/

        select @TABLE_NAME = min(TABLE_NAME) from seuBanco.information_schema.tables
            where TABLE_NAME > @TABLE_NAME
    end
```

Portanto, ao criar os *triggers*, bastaria substituir parte de seus nomes e a tabela a que eles se referem pela variável `@TABLE_NAME`.

Comment: vlw, já consigo ver a luz no fim do túnel agora :) (nem um pouco dramático)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar a seguinte trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER duplica BEFORE INSERT ON contatos
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.telefone2 = NEW.telefone;
```