# SQL Server 2005 e controle de versão da linha

Tags: sql-server, versionamento, tsql, sql-server-2005

No meu atual cenário, toda sexta-feira, eu preciso listar todas as linhas de uma tabela que foram adicionadas ou alteradas.

Nesta tabela temos um campo `DataDeInclusao` que recebe, obviamente, a data de inclusão daquele registro.

Meu problema é listar os registros alterados desde uma determinada data. Adicionar um campo do tipo `timestamp` ou `rowversion` não armazenam a informação "quando".

Para isso pensei em utilizar uma *trigger* na tabela que quero controlar e desta forma atualizar um campo (DataDaUltimaAlteracao).

Seria este o melhor caminho? O que vocês fariam?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, esse é o caminho que eu adotaria até por questões de auditoria (de quebra eu também usaria um campo para identificar o usuário que fez a alteração, mas isso não vem ao caso). Para o SQL Server 2005 você pode usar um valor *default* `GETDATE()` ou (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) para a data de inserção e um *trigger* para a data de atualização. Para o SQL Server 2008+ você pode usar a função `SYSDATETIME()` e o tipo mais preciso `DATETIME2`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MinhaTabela
(  
   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   -- suas colunas
   DataDeInclusao  DATETIME NOT NULL
       CONSTRAINT DF_MinhaTabela_Inclusao DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
   DataDeAtualizacao DATETIME NULL -- Ou com DEFAULT de acordo com seus requisitos
);

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TRG_MinhaTabelaAtualizada
ON dbo.MinhaTabela
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
    UPDATE dbo.MinhaTabela
    SET DataDeAtualizacao = GETDATE()
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE i.ID = dbo.MinhaTabela.ID;
```

Veja que para atender ao seu requisito apenas um coluna `DataUltimaAtualizacao` (com a *constraint default* e o *trigger*) seria suficiente, mas é sempre bom diferenciar inserção de atualização.

Finalmente, não se esqueça de indexar as duas datas (para otimizar as suas consultas).

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_MinhaTabelaInclusao ON  dbo.MinhaTabela(DataDeInclusao);
CREATE INDEX IDX_MinhaTabelaAtualizacao ON  dbo.MinhaTabela(DataDeAtualizacao);
```

[**Exemplo no SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa2e1a/1)

---

**Fontes**:

- [SOE - created and modified timestamp in sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259659/created-and-modified-timestamp-in-sql-server-2008)
- [SOE - How do I add a “last updated” column in a SQL Server 2008 R2 table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349288/how-do-i-add-a-last-updated-column-in-a-sql-server-2008-r2-table)

Answer (score 3):

É isso mesmo. O correto é uma coluna chamada `DataDeAlteracao` do tipo `DateTime`, atualizável por *trigger*.

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12521/2999), ensino um comando a criar uma *trigger* para cada tabela da sua base de dados. Pode ser útil se você pretende auditar todas as tabelas.

`timestamp` e `rowversion` não são adequados para controle da última data de alteração porque não guardam uma data propriamente dita, e sim um número binário que é alterado toda vez que a linha é alterada. O intuito desse tipo de dados é simplesmente resolver conflitos de concorrência, para sistemas grandes e muito acessados em níveis de leitura e escrita.